# fallback function msg.sender error;

Tags: solidity, remix

The code is as following, if Contract send ether to Contract Receiver, I will recevice: 
transact to Sender.send errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.

However, if I annotate line "addr = msg.sender;" "amount = msg.value;" everything is ok, and I will receive the event log

`pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract Receiver {
    address public addr;
    uint public amount;
    event log(address, uint);
    function() payable{
        addr = msg.sender;
        amount = msg.value;
        log(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
    function Receiver() public payable {
        addr = msg.sender;
        amount = msg.value;
    }
}`


`contract Sender{
    function send(address addr, uint amount) payable{
        addr.transfer(amount);
    }
    function getBalance() payable returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }
    function Sender() payable{ }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling a fallback function with either `send()` or `transfer()` on another contract (which is what is happening when you call `send(address addr, uint amount)` in the Sender contract) there is a restricted allowance of 2300 gas for security reasons. Unfortunately 2300 gas is not enough to do these instructions `addr = msg.sender; amount = msg.value;`.

In order to execute those instructions and receive Ether at the same time, you will need to create a payable named function, not fallback, in the Receiver contract which the Sender contract calls explicitly.

Comment: I have already tried this method, but the same error I got.
`pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract Receiver{
    uint public value;
    event log(address, uint256);
    function() payable public{
        test();
    }
    function test() payable{
        value = msg.value;
        log(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
    
    function Receiver() payable{}
    
}

contract Sender{
    function send(address addr, uint amount){
        addr.transfer(amount);
    }
    function Sender() payable{}
}`

Comment: Replace `addr.transfer(amount);` with `Receiver(addr).test.value(amount)();`. This casts the `addr` to an instance on the Receiver contract then calls the function `test()` on that contract and sends the `amount` of ether with `value()`. This way you will no longer be calling the fallback function which restricts you to 2300 gas. See a few paragraphs down in [this part of the doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#members-of-addresses) for an explanation of `.value()`

Comment: I find many ICO contract on Github interacts with storage variables or calls other function(I failed in the same way), for example [Contract](https://github.com/ByteHeroes/herocoin/blob/master/contracts/HeroCoin.sol)
The fallback function interacts with `balances`; Therefore, these contracts contain errors?

Comment: The 2300 gas restriction is applied when you use either `send()` or `transfer()` from within a contract to another contract, like your Sender contract does. If you send a transaction to the Receiver contract normally, from outside any smart contracts, there is no 2300 gas restriction.